# Array to string conversion (laravel 7)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a quiz app in Laravel and I've got some error: `array to string conversion`

This is my controller:

```
public function validateForm1($request)
{
    return $this->validate($request, [
        'quiz_id'        => 'required',
        'question'       => 'required',
        'options'        => 'required|array',
        'options.*'      => 'required|string',
        'correct_answer' => 'required',
    ]);
}

public function buat(Request $request)
{
    $data = $this->validateForm1($request);
    $question = (new Pertanyaan)->storeQuestion($data);
    $Answer =  (new Jawaban)->storeAnswer($data,$question);    
               
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Pertanyaan berhasil disimpan');        
}
```

This is my question model:

```
public function storeQuestion($data)
{           
    return Pertanyaan::create($data);
}
```

This is my answer model:

```
public function storeAnswer($data, $question)
{
    foreach ($data['options'] as $key => $option) {
        
        $is_correct = false;
       
        if ($key == $data['correct_answer']) {
            $is_correct = true;
        }

        $answer = Jawaban::create([
            'question_id' => $question->id,
            'answer'      => $option,
            'is_correct'  => $is_correct,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the stack trace?

Comment: hi sir im new in laravel and programming.. what should i do for print out the stack trace ?

Comment: Stack trace is sequence of errors you’ll see on your browser while accessing your laravel application.

Comment: `Array to string conversation` can you show us the more details about this error? Like line number and actual error message.

Comment: this is the stack trace sir,
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
C:\xampp\htdocs\xgens_academy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php:449

Comment: Can you show the input you call the endpoint with?

Comment: u mean the route right ?

Comment: There should be a lot more to the stack trace. Laravel should also be logging the error to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. I would suggest either clearing the file or deleting it, doing whatever you did to get the error again and then copying the contents of the `laravel.log` file to your question (please edit your question rather than adding it as a comment).

Comment: _I want to make a quiz app in Laravel and I've got some error: `array to string conversion`_ Alright, do you have a specific question? We can't debug your entire program for you. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: thanks for replying my problem sir. now its solved when i changed guarded with fillable in my model. 
thakyou so much

Comment: should i post my blade.php too for debug ? but when i try to edit this post i got some warning and cannot update my post. im new here sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
return $this->validate($request, [
    'quiz_id'        => 'required',
    'question'       => 'required',
    'options'        => 'required|array',
    'correct_answer' => 'required',
]);
```

Then your error remove automatically `array to string conversion`

Answer (score 0):

this error i got when i use guarded in model, so i change it to fillable and it work properly.
sorry if im not capturing all of my model.

after read the documentation about special variable eloquent, i lil understand.
here the link i read but in indonesian leanguage. and sorry for my bad english sir. im new here

https://id-laravel.com/post/mengenal-eloquent-variable-spesial/

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, it was caused by an error in my Model. I had the table name formatted as an array, like `protected $table = ['log'];`. Correcting this to `protected $table = 'log';` fixed the problem.